# How to solve object not found?

Tags: r

I'm using spectra indices code for hyperspectral data. https://github.com/serbinsh/R-FieldSpectra  this is the link for the program I am using. I get to step 2, in line 19 I receive an error for object 'dims' not found. This is the line of code where I receive the error.

`for (i in 1:dims[1]){ print(paste("File: ",spectra$Spectra[i],sep="")) }`

Comment: Please, try to provide minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because there is no object `dims`.

Try changing it to `for (i in 1:dim(spectra)[1])`, which will loop over the rows (1st dimension) of the data frame `spectra`.

Comment: Would you mind marking this as solved if it answered your question?